# How to retrieve data from SalesForce using C#

Tags: c#, salesforce

Could somebody help me find an example of getting data from SalesForce using its api with c#? E.g. getting a Contact information by its email address?

Comment: You seen https://github.com/wadewegner/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET ?

Comment: @eyescream I have not. But I am afraid it is not well supported, as last time it was updated 2 years ago...

Comment: Old, stable, battle-tested or you want to craft the SOAP / REST messages yourself, read up about security tokens, oauth scopes, error handling, bulk API options? I'd offload at least the login part to existing library but your call :) there are many ways to connect, there's even (paid) SQL server plugin or azure data factory solution... We're in time-to-market world

Comment: @eyescream, I will try to apply it. But it is not clear to me where I can take consumer key and consumer secret.

Comment: If you call SOAP API's login (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm - but really going best is to export WSDL and consume in your code?) - you need only username, password and optionally "security token". But the .NET app will have access to everything your user has.

Comment: If you want to limit the access using OAuth2 scopes (or even better don't store credentials in the app, make user type them in interactively and then the access is on their rights instead of admin) - you'll need to log in using call REST API, like https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm. Start in https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_create.htm&type=5, you generate OAuth2 key and secret in there

Comment: @eyescream Thank you for your suggestion about Force.com. If you make it an Answer, I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ready-built libraries for .NET integration such as https://github.com/wadewegner/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET, I'd suggest starting with one of these. (old but [official](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/01/announcing-the-salesforce-toolkits-for-net)). Another one could be https://github.com/anthonyreilly/NetCoreForce

Old, stable, battle-tested or you want to craft the SOAP / REST messages yourself, read up about security tokens, oauth scopes, error handling, bulk API options? I'd offload at least the login part to existing library but your call :) There are many ways to connect, there's even (paid) [SQL server plugin](https://www.cdata.com/dbamp/) or azure data factory solution...

".NET toolkit" seems to use old SOAP API. It's... simple. You provide username, password and you get total impersonation. The app will be able to do everything the connecting user can do. The other one seems to use client id and secret, this sounds like newer REST-based API implementation (OAuth2 keys). This is slightly better, you get extra security layer of the connected app and for example if "scope" is only set to Chatter - even admin's session connecting via this app can't be abused.

There are slight differences between the APIs and the way they handle certain features (for example downloading a Document/Attachment/File via SOAP API will give you base64-encoded payload while REST API will give you a link to download the binary separately). And of course how much of the API does the library actually implement, how well it's maintained...

But generally I'd say explore the libraries first. At least steal some ideas around login logic. If nothing off-the-shelf works for you - consume the WSDL and hand-craft something in SOAP API. Worst case - craft the XML messages manually, worry about escaping special characters etc.

Answer (score 1):

Get an account and api key and then use the official programming interface:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/apis

i'd choose: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_resources.htm

So You have to read and understand this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_working_with_searches_and_queries.htm

:)

Comment: Thank you, I will check this.